# How can I access a remote machine via SSH from behind a proxy?

Tags: terminal, ssh, proxy

I’m trying to connect to a Linux machine via SSH. The problem is that my Mac is in a different network, behind a proxy that routes HTTP and HTTPS through port 80.

How can I access the Linux machine via SSH from terminal?

Connecting with `-vvv` returns the following result:

```
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to _example.com_ [_ip_address_] port 22.
debug1: connect to address _ip_address_ port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host _example.com_ port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: SSH doesn't use HTTP or HTTPS, so from your description the web proxy is irrelevant. Possibly there is a firewall preventing you from connecting to the standard SSH port (22)?

Comment: @Gerry I am behind a firewall, yes. And I’m interested in a solution to make it work in these conditions.

Comment: Hard to say, if the firewall effectively blocks everything except web traffic via the web proxy, there is no way to directly connect via SSH to your host. If the firewall allows traffic outside on different ports, you can configure your SSH server to listen on another port than the default.

Comment: Can you try to connect using the -vvv argument and edit the question with the output?

Comment: @WarrenPena, see the edit to my question.

Comment: http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/ssh-via-http-proxy-in-osx.html

Comment: Basically, that trace tells us that data from your computer to the server's port 22 is being refused by whatever machine it's ending up at.  There are numerous things that could cause this.  Here are some more questions to help pinpoint the exact cause: Can you SSH from the server to itself?  If not, then perhaps the SSH daemon isn't running, or it's on a different port.  Is there a firewall on the server itself or on the path in-between that could be eating the connection attempt?  Your trace leads me to believe you gave a domain name to SSH.  Is it resolving to the correct IP address?

Answer (score -1):

You may need tunneling technique for accessing an HTTP proxy using SSH tunneling check this link: http://kimmo.suominen.com/docs/proxy-through-ssh/

Comment: They're trying to connect to SSH, not HTTP.

Comment: The question says: How can I access the Linux machine via SSH from terminal?

Comment: The server administrator should give them a VPN and provide access to SSH (port 22) through the proxy.